# Accessing the cucumber test from StepDefs

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

When creating a cucumber test, one defines a `feature`file with the defined tests and a `class`file with the exact same name in the same package to run the test.
(I'll leave the `Cucumber.options` for what they are at the moment).

As far as I understood it correctly, Cucumber will look in that same package and all its sub-packages for the `Step Definitions` file to execute the corresponding step in the current scenario. (Again, I leave the `Cucumber.options` for what they are).

Is there any way to find the link between the test class that's being executed and the StepDefs class that's handling the current step being executed?

```
src/
\_ test/
   \_ java/
   |  \_ test.cucumber.package
   |     \_ MyTest1.class
   |     \_ MyTest2.class
   |     \_ StepDefs1.class
   |     \_ StepDefs2.class
   \_ resources/
      \_ test.cucumber.package
         \_ MyTest1.feature
         \_ MyTest2.feature
```

So, MyTest1.class executes the steps defined in MyTest1.feature.  The implementation of those steps could be defined in either StepDefs1.class or StepDefs2.class.
The same goes for MyTest2.

1) How do I know if a step is defined in StepDefs1 or StepDefs2?

2) When a step is executed, how do I know if it's executed for MyTest1 or MyTest2?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work-around by creating a singleton TestStepDefLink class.  I can then contact this class both from the Test and from the Step Defs.
The moment the test is started, I get an instance of the TestStepDefLink object and set the testId variable.  Once the stepDefs are executed, I get the testStepDefLink instance and read the value of the testId variable

It did come up that cucumber never creates an instance of the test class, only of the StepDef classes. So I have to create a Test class instance myself.